# IF returns certain value if cell contains a certain phrase, but no blanks/N/A in between

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I've tried looking for an answer to this online for a few hours now, but I just can't work out how you'd describe it, or find an appropriate answer.

I have a spreadsheet where I'm wanting to pull out an ID in Column A into a separate tab, but only if it contains a certain phrase that's contained in Column E. In this separate tab, I then don't want there to be any gaps in between the IF statements.

So for example I want the next tab to pull through the Action ID if column E contains 'Client'. If it doesn't, it searches the next row and so on until it finds one that does contain 'Client'. Row 2 on the separate tab would then continue the search, but it wouldn't be filled with something if it doesn't find the word 'Client' - it instead would continue searching down until it found one that has the word in.

[image: Base spreadsheet columns A to F]

So for example - if the first ID that contains the right phrase is in Row 5, I want it to appear on the separate tab in Row 2, underneath the heading. Then, if the second ID with the correct phrase in column F is in Row 11 for example on the main tab, I then want it to be pulled through to Row 3 on the separate tab. And so on..

This will then allow me to do lookups for the rest of the values I want to input on the separate tab.

[image]

I've tried as many different IF statements as I can, but it's just not having it.

Any advice would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `INDEX` and `AGGREGATE` combination:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$6,AGGREGATE(15,6,1/($E$2:$E$6="Client")*ROW($E$2:$E$6)-1,ROW()-1)),"")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks - how do I do this on a different tab? I'd ideally like it to pull into a dedicated Client tab if possible. Otherwise - this is pretty much exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Copy the formula on the sheet you want and add the name of the corresponding sheet with an exclamation mark before each range in formula. Eg ```Sheet1!$A$2:$A$6```

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Do you know what the equivalent would be for Google Sheets?

Answer (score 0):

In Google Sheets you can use `FILTER` ([docs](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en)) for that. Place it in the top cell of your column.

```
={
  "Your Header";
  IFNA(FILTER(A2:A, B2:B = "Client"))
}
```

If `A2:A` and `B2:B` are from other tab named `My Tab` it will be `'My Tab'!A2:A` and `'My Tab'!B2:B`.

[image]